# What does [::] mean in `https://[::]:8808`?

Tags: http, web

When I run `gem server`, it sees as below. What does `[::]` mean?

```
Server started at http://[::]:8808
Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8808
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::` is the all-zeroes IPv6 address. The messages mean that the server will accept connections on any available IPv6 interface as well as any IPv4 one.